# How to make a sigmoid between $-1$ and $1$

Tags: linear-regression

I am trying to make a sigmoid which ranges from $-1$ to $1$.

I have found the formula $\dfrac{1}{​1+​e^{​\, ‑x}}-​0.5$ which creates a sigmoid between $-0.5$ and $0.5$

I need an equation that I can input $x$ and will get you the value for $y$

E.g. $y = x+5$

Comment: Why did you down vote? Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y(x) = \frac{2}{1+e^{-x}} -1 = 2 \sigma(x) - 1 = \tanh(x/2)$, where $\sigma$ is the standard sigmoid and $\tanh$ is the hyperbolic tangent. Twice the range, shifted down by one. Pick your favorite form.

Comment: What would the equation be in the format of y=

Comment: The y = was implied.

Comment: Oh ok didn't realise. Thanks for the good answer. I will accept it as the answer as soon as it lets me. Any idea why they down voted?

Comment: They probably thought you could think this one through.

Comment: Oh. Well that's a shame, some people need help with certain problems and that is the point of this website. Down voting because they know it and you don't spoils the point